# Express 4: Middleware branching

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an Express application in which I'm using middleware to format my response after my route handlers. As such, after adding data to the `res` object, all of my routes are calling `next()` to call the formatter.

I want to handle 404s logically. However, I can't use app middleware easily for this as all of my route handlers call `next()`; creating a catchall route (`app.use('*', 404function...)`) means that everything becomes a 404 error, even routes that are correct.

Is there a way to tell whether a route did not match anything in the handlers? Alternatively, is there a way to have a route specifically call error middleware (a function with an arity of 4)?

Comment: the 404 handler would need to go after your formatter, or be a part of it.

Comment: @KevinB I was hoping it wouldn't have to be a part of it. Basically, it's a success handler that formats my json in [JSend](http://labs.omniti.com/labs/jsend) format - returning a 200 status unless there's actually an error. This is what's being called by `next()`. With Patrick Murphy's answer, I can have the 404 only fall through if the route didn't match, instead of one handler overriding the other.

Comment: His answer basically does what i was suggesting, just in the opposite direction. Maybe i just wasn't clear enough. basically, if your formatter has data to format and return, it does, and if not, it calls next(). your 404 and error handlers then catch it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if [`req.route`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#req.route) is defined in your formatter. If so, the request matched a route and you can format the response data; otherwise, either generate a 404 on the spot or pass it on using `next`.

Comment: That worked perfectly. I figured there was something like this, but I didn't think about `req.route` - I figured that any routing path would have always been defined, since that's what you're calling. Awesome!